# Class Notfound exception in sqlserver connection in eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server, servlets

My servlet function looks like these:

CODE:

```
         protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)       throws ServletException, IOException {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String userName;
        String passwd;
        Connection conn = null;

        userName = (String)request.getParameter("userName");
        passwd = (String)request.getParameter("password");
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); //Or any other driver

        }
        catch( Exception x ){
                System.out.println( "Couldn’t load drivers!" ); 
        }
        try
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.123:1433;databaseName=test","sample","sample");
        }
        catch( Exception x)
        {
            System.out.println("Couldnot get connection");
        }
    }
```

the output goes to two catch statements.How to overcome this?

Reply as soon as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running this from within Eclipse? It looks like you need to add a the driver JAR file to your dependencies. You can do this from the project build path settings within Eclipse (right-click the project, select Build Path -> Configure Build Path). Then under the 'Libraries' tab you can add any jars needed, such as the SQL server driver JAR file.

If you are deploying this to a Servlet container, it looks like the JAR file is missing from the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. Copy it here and you should find it works.

Comment: I copied in the WEB-INF/lib folder but it is not showing in the eclipse.how to overcome this?

Comment: @karthik Have you tried refreshing the Eclipse project? (Right-click -> Refresh). Then you can add that JAR file to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.123:1433;databaseName=test", "sample", "sample");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println( "Couldn’t load drivers!" );
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldnot get connection");
    }
```

or

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.123:1433;databaseName=test", "sample", "sample");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ClassNotFoundException) {
             System.out.println( "Couldn’t load drivers!" );
        } else {
            if (e instanceof SQLException) {
                System.out.println("Couldnot get connection");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your answer is not relevant to my question.