# connect to sql server using jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 using JDBC. My SQL Server 2008  has windows authentication on it.

My code is

```
public class T1 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
private static void Connect(){
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl =        "jdbc:sqlserver://servername;databaseName=employee;user=username;password=''/*since it is windows authentication*/;";
        java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SQLException e2)
    {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    T1.Connect();

}
```

I end up getting a ClassNotFoundException .

The stack trace is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)`

Comment: 1) post the stacktrace 2) is connector jar in classpath?

Comment: Did you read Microsoft documentation?

Comment: [Possibly Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372815/class-notfound-exception-in-sqlserver-connection-in-eclipse)  If you are using the command prompt refer here for classpath usage [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526048/classnotfoundexception-when-connecting-to-mysql-with-jdbc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ClassNotFoundException likely means that you don't have the SQL*Server drivers available on your classpath

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Eclipse as your development environment, do the following:

1. Right-click on your project in eclipse.
2. Click on "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path"
3. You will be in the "Libraries" tab by default. Now, click on "Add External Jars" and add the JDBC Driver Jar for MSSQL Server. (In case you don't have it, download it from [JDBC Driver for MSSQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=11774)
4. Click on OK and try running your program again.

Reply back if you still face issues.